# Rails library to process an RSS/ATOM feed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, rss, atom-feed

What's a good solution to parse an RSS/ATOM feed and present the content in a Rails view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen good notes on the parsing part at http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2005/05/11/parsing-a-rss-feed (and links therefrom).  How to best present things once you have parsed them is maybe a bit of a subjective issue...

Answer (score 3):

One of the [recent Railscasts (6/29/2009)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/168-feed-parsing) recommended Feedzirra

Answer (score 0):

id recommend acts_as_feed, which takes care of parsing automatically [acts as feed rails plugin](http://github.com/grosser/acts_as_feed) and can be added to models. Another solution would be to use [google feed api](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/) as long as you only need to display the feed.

```
#HAML view example
- if feed.filled?
  %h2="Blog: #{feed.title}"
  - for item in feed.entries[0...5]
    -date = item.published_at.to_date.to_s(:long)

    %h2=link_to(h(item.title),h(item.url))
```